# JavaScript - remove milliseconds from date object

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get the date for the next Sunday (and set the time to 9am:

```
var sun = new Date();
sun.setDate(sun.getDate() + (7 - sun.getDay()));
sun.setHours(9);
sun.setMinutes(0);
sun.setSeconds(0);
console.log(sun.toISOString());
```

This is what I get:

```
  2018-11-04T09:00:00.722Z
```

The only thing that I don't need is .722 (API will not accept that)

```
2018-11-04T09:00:00Z
```

How do I remove the .722 bit?

Comment: [`sun.setMilliseconds(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds)

Comment: @Pointy that comment should be an answer (the answer, imo)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was looking for a duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to split your `toISOString()` with `.` using [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), grab the **0th** index and concatenate the literal `Z` with the output. This way you can simply ignore the **1st** index that contains the milliseconds value. Hope this helps :)

```js
var sun = new Date();
sun.setDate(sun.getDate() + (7 - sun.getDay()));
sun.setHours(9);
sun.setMinutes(0);
sun.setSeconds(0);
console.log(sun.toISOString().split('.')[0]+"Z");
```

Comment: @Wasteland you're welcome. Glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck

Comment: @Wasteland there's no reason to do that instead of simply setting the milliseconds to zero just like you set the minutes and seconds.

Comment: @don'tangryme ah well if the API won't accept three zeros (which would mean that it's incorrectly parsing the date format) then you're right.

Comment: Yes sir, as OP pointed *(API will not accept that)* that's why I've posted with the split way otherwise I also will go with `setMIlliseconds(0)`. Thanks..

Answer (score 7):

One option might be to do a regex replacement on the timestamp string, after you have generated it:

```js
var ts = "2018-11-04T09:00:00.722Z";
console.log(ts);
ts = ts.replace(/\.\d+/, "");
console.log(ts);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [setMilliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds) on the Date object to set the wanted miliseconds amount.

```
var sun = new Date();
sun.setDate(sun.getDate() + (7 - sun.getDay()));
sun.setHours(9);
sun.setMinutes(0);
sun.setSeconds(0);
sun.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(sun.toISOString());
```

Example output:

```
2022-06-12T13:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: That would still print it though.

Answer (score 1):

It's milliseconds you see, which you can also remove like below. Also you can use .setHours() only to remove mins and seconds.

```js
var sun = new Date();
sun.setDate(sun.getDate() + (7 - sun.getDay()));
sun.setHours(9,0,0,0)
console.log(sun.toISOString().slice(0,-5) + 'Z');
```

Comment: ms sometimes can be one symbol after dot, i will not recommend slice

Comment: If that would be the case then "split" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

One other option:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMilliseconds(0);
var dateISOString = date.toISOString().replace(".000Z", "Z");

console.log(dateISOString);
```

OUTPUT:

> 2021-06-16T10:08:41Z